# Alternatives to DirectAdmin?

Tags: web-hosting, server

I'm currently using Direct Admin and quite happy with it, however feel it is a bit overpriced, and as I'm adding a new server, wanted to see if there are any other tools I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [WebMin](http://www.webmin.com/) for Unix/Linux machines, or [eBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/eBox) (now called Zentyal) which is available for Ubuntu, both are open source free applications which should save you some money

> Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix.
>   Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache,
>   DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually
>   edit Unix configuration files like /etc/passwd, and lets you manage a
>   system from the console or remotely.